# Python class creation like C#

Tags: python

Does Python have any syntax that allows you to create an instance of a class and set property values on it within the same statement

You can do this in C# like this

```
StudentName student2 = new StudentName
{
    FirstName = "Craig",
    LastName = "Playstead",
};
```

Is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: You can define defaults in `__init__` method which is constructor equivalent

Comment: I need to be able to set specific values for each instance, being able to do this in a single statement would greatly simplify my code.

Comment: check out `_slots_` https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059785/1344855

Comment: @toefftoefftoeff `__slots__` is an advanced feature that's very rarely needed in real life. I'm not sure how it would apply here much, anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really. The Pythonic ways to express this might be one of the following.

## A regular old class

```
class StudentName:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

student2 = StudentName(first_name="Craig", last_name="Playstead")
```

(You can also add a `, *,` argument after `self` to force users to spell out the keyword names see [Keyword (Named) Arguments in Python](https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/).)

## A namedtuple

```
import collections
StudentName = collections.namedtuple("StudentName", "first_name last_name")

student2 = StudentName(first_name="Craig", last_name="Playstead")
```

Namedtuples also act like tuples, so you can use `student2[0]` to access `first_name` and `[1]` for `last_name`.

## A `dataclass` (Python 3.7+)

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class StudentName:
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

student2 = StudentName(first_name="Craig", last_name="Playstead")
```

---

Comment: Useful to know about dataclasses!

Comment: Thanks. I can make it worked with named parameters, I have control of the classes being created so I can add all the properties in as optional parameters.
The dataclass solution looks pretty neat, but I think the 3.7 requirement is to limiting for us.

Answer (score 1):

```
class StudentName:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
         self.firstname = firstname
         self.lastname = lastname


name = StudentName('firstname', 'lastname')
```

If you want to specifically set which property is which in the constructor:

```
class StudentName:
    def __init__(self, firstname='', lastname=''):
         self.firstname = firstname
         self.lastname = lastname


name = StudentName(firstname='firstname', lastname='lastname')
```

You can then also create a `StudentName` like so: `StudentName()`. His first and lastname would be `''`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define defaults in `__init__` method which is constructor equivalent

```
class Student():
  def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname

  def __str__(self):
     return "My name is {} {}".format(self.firstname, self.lastname)

s1 = Student("John", "Smith")
print(s1)
```